# Paint peeled off with wall border sticker

Tags: walls, paint

Yesterday I tried removing a (childish) wall border sticker from my wall.
I used steam from a kettle to try and melt the glue, but it didn't work for some places.
Is there a simple fix for this, or do I need to paint the whole wall all over again?
Thanks!

[image: pic1]

[image: pic2]

Comment: How old is the paint job?

Answer (score 5):

If this were my wall I would:

1. Scrape off all loose paint.
2. Sand area with sanding block - heavy grit.
3. Feather in joint compound.  Do another coat.
4. Sand area until flat.
5. Prime beyond damaged area.
6. Repaint.